# Secret hash issue when run once-off job in kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

When using kustomize, I am trying to use `job` to perform some once-off job. But somehow, the kustomize just doesn't recognise hashed `secret`. The below is the relevant codes.

```
.
├── base
│   └── postgres.yaml
├── jobs
│   ├── postgres-cli.yaml
│   └── kustomization.yaml
└── overlays
    └── dev
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        └── postgres-secrects.properties
```

base/postgres.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:14-alpine
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: postgres-secrets
# ...
```

overlays/dev/kustomization.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ../../base/postgres.yaml

secretGenerator:
  - name: postgres-secrets
    envs:
      - postgres-secrets.properties
```

base/overlays/dev/postgres-secrects.properties

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
```

jobs/postgres-cli.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: postgres-cli
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: postgres-cli
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - image: my-own-image
          name: postgres-cli
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: postgres-secrets # errors here cannot cannot recognise
# ...
```

jobs/kustomization.yaml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1

kind: Component

commonLabels:
  environment: local

resources:
  - ./postgres-cli.yaml
```

To start my stack, I run `kubectl apply -k ./overlay/dev`.

Then, when I try to run the `postgres-cli`, I try to run `kubectl apply -k /jobs`, it complains like below: `secret "postgres-secrets" not found`

Do we have a way to find the secret back when apply the job?

Answer (score 0):

```html
.
├── base
│   └── postgres.yaml
├── jobs
│   ├── postgres-cli.yaml
│   └── kustomization.yaml
└── overlays
    └── dev
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        └── postgres-secrects.properties
```

Having this structure it means that the secret is in the overlay at dev level. You try to run the job from one level below and the sercret is not there. To run this you have two ways or by kubectl apply -k ./overlay/dev. or by moving the overlay into jobs and create only one kustomization.

Comment: If I put everything into one kustomization, those command will be run at beginning and also I cannot run it when I need to run.